# Simple rule engine to replace if statements with AND condition

Tags: java, rule-engine

I have some simple conditions:

```
if(source.equals("something") && target.equals("something")){
        // suggested tool (high priority)
        // suggested another tool (low priority)
    }

else if (...){
        // suggested some other tool
    }
.....
```

There are around 50 conditions. It can grow later.

- *There is only `&&` condition*
- *priority can be a number between 1 to 5.*

I can provide a csv input file like:

```
source,target,tool,priority
abc,xyz,xxx,5
abc,xyz,yyy,3
...
```

Possible ways I can think of:

- read this csv file
- convert it into objects and persist it in the embedded database
- query the database and fetch the highest priority tool

This is not the best way as the number of conditions is few (*around 50*).

**Is there any simple rule engine that can do this work?**

Comment: ehm ..; so, what is it you're actually asking?

Comment: @Stultuske As mentioned in the question - Is there any simple rule engine that can solve this?

Comment: solve 'what'? there is no problem described, so what is it you have, what is it you try to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Stultuske check updated question

Comment: you still haven't put anything yet that needs "solving"

Comment: You don't really need a database though? I mean... why not just write the objects in a HashMap with source+target as the key and a list of tool+priority as the value? That way you can easily get to any tool suggestion list (which you can simply sort by priority)?

Comment: @Mark this can be an option and yes its better than persisting in db

Comment: You could compose a condition in Javascript and execute the script through the java api. If you use Java 7 or higher version, the javascript interpeter is integrated, for lower version have a look to Mozilla Rhino. If you have in mind something like a rule engine try [drools](http://www.drools.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Every rule engine can do this:)
Try engines for Java like Jess, Drools, or more lighweight solutions like HeaRTDroid, or EasyRules.